# Converting hexadecimal to a char that has 3 digits

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, hex

I have a problem converting hexadecimal to a character when the hexadecimal has 3 digits

I have 2 methods which escape and unescape characters over decimal value 127

`test\\b8` is produced when `test¸` is escaped

The unescape does the following:

```
for (int i=0, n=node.length; i<n; i++) {
    if(c == "\\"){
          char c2 = node[i + 1];
          char c3 = node[i + 2];
          int i= Integer.parseInt(str,16);
          char c = (char)i;
          System.out.println("Char is:=" + c);
    }
}
```

output - `test¸`

As you can see I take the first two characters after the slash and convert them into a char. This all works fine. However there are sometimes characters that have 3 hexadecimal digits (for example `test\\2d8`. This should unescape as `test˘`). When this enters into my unescape method is won't use all 3 characters. Only the first 2 and therefore the produce wrong results.

Is there a way to determine when to convert 2 or 3 characters

Comment: You have `(c == "\\")`, should that instead be in single quotes?

Comment: Give an example of the input and the output you are getting and the output you expect to get.  It sounds like your unescape method is the problem.

Comment: Are you just trying to convert a number to its utf-8 character? If so, convert each character to hex and use a Reader set to read utf-8 to read it

Comment: Have you tried using the toChars(int codePoint) (static) method on the Character class?

Comment: Can you zero pad it?  Also, what are you doing with this?  It's certainly already been done before...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
String raw = new String(node); // might be a better way to get a string from the chars
int slashPos = raw.indexOf('\\');
if(slashPos >= 0) {
    String hex = raw.substring(slashPos + 1);
    int value = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
}
```

In this manner, we're not special casing anything for 2, 3, 4, or 100 digits (although I'm sure 100 digits would throw an exception :-) ). Instead, we're using the protocol as a 'milestone' in the string, and then just accepting that everything after the slash is the hex string.

```
class HexParse {

    private static class HexResult {
        final boolean exists;
        final int value;
        HexResult(boolean e, int v) { exists = e; value = v; }
    }

    private final String raw;
    private final HexResult result;

    public HexParse(String raw) {
        this.raw = raw;
        int slashPos = raw.indexOf('\\');
        boolean noSlash = slashPos < 0;
        boolean noTextAfterSlash = slashPos > raw.length() - 2;
        if(noSlash || noTextAfterSlash) {
            result  = new HexResult(false,0);
        } else {
            // throws exception if second part of string contains non-hex chars
            result = new HexResult(true,Integer.parseInt(raw.substring(slashPos + 1),16));
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(raw).append(" ");
        if(result.exists) {
            sb.append("has hex of decimal value ").append(result.value);
        } else {
            sb.append("has no hex");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String...args) {
        System.out.println(new HexParse("test`hello")); // none
        System.out.println(new HexParse("haha\\abcdef")); // hex
        System.out.println(new HexParse("good\\f00d")); // hex
        System.out.println(new HexParse("\\84b")); // hex
        System.out.println(new HexParse("\\")); // none
        System.out.println(new HexParse("abcd\\efgh")); //exception
    }

}

c:\files\j>javac HexParse.java

c:\files\j>java HexParse
test`hello has no hex
haha\abcdef has hex of decimal value 11259375
good\f00d has hex of decimal value 61453
\84b has hex of decimal value 2123
\ has no hex
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e
fgh"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.
java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
        at HexParse.<init>(HexParse.java:21)
        at HexParse.main(HexParse.java:
```

Comment: Well, since it has no slashes, it would return `-1`. I would recommend using a customized response object, perhaps with a ResponseEnum and a ResponseValue, rather than just using `-1`.

Comment: @Decrypter I edited in a more robust solution with a response value. It doesn't use an enum because there were only two options (value exists or value doesn't). I could have made it even more robust with an enum of `HexExists`, `NoSecondTerm`, `SecondTermNotHex`, and maybe even a couple other states. But I figured it was ... 'enough'...

Comment: Apologies my previously example was wrong I meant `test\\2d8hello`

Comment: No, it would be impossible to do that. Consider the phrase `test\\3dbale`. Is that `test`-`3d`-`bale` or is it `test`-`3db`-`ale`? If you are going to have tokens after the hex, you must have a seperator token, or guarantee a fixed (or otherwise known) number of digits, or some other way of knowing where the hex stops and the next word starts.